# Attaching an event listener for left or right click - onclick doesn't work for right click

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, web-inspector

I am currently applying for an Internship [Internship Link](https://hire.jobvite.com/CompanyJobs/Careers.aspx?c=qLY9Vfwx&s=LINKEDIN&nl=1&page=Apply&j=oeJg0fwX)

One of the things that I noticed right away is that you click on upload cover letter or paste cover letter, you're redirected to the home page of the job invite site [Job Invite](http://www.jobvite.com/#) and sadly you can't upload your cover letter. On the other hand, the upload resume works perfectly fine but paste resume has the same issue.
Does anyone know how to resolve this issue and and be able to submit a cover letter?

I am not a web guru  but since I am applying for an engineering position, I am trying to find a way around this. I right clicked the upload cover letter link and inspected the link with the inspect element tool. I found that this function

```
onclick="jvAddAttachment2('jvcoverletter', 'qLY9Vfwx')
```

was going to get called when the button is clicked. Now going into the JavaScript file for this html page, Inspect Element -> Sources -> *careers_8.js?v=303, I tried to do a basic alert statement, from [alert dialog](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp), to do some debugging to see what the issue is. Here's the code now

```
function jvAddAttachment2(id, companyId){
    alert("I got here");
    ....
}
```

I then did control s and the Inspect Element console outputted "Recompilation and update succeeded." so I am assuming the JavaScript file has been updated. However when I click the link(via right click, open new window), no alert box shows up.
 Does anyone know  how to get the alert dialog to show up? I think I've done as much as I can with my working knowledge from one web development course haha.

Comment: You can call the function into your js console : `jvAddAttachment2('jvcoverletter', 'qLY9Vfwx')` Then you won't be redirected (I think the faulty function is the `hideDiv()` one)

Comment: @Kaiido How did you figure that out?

Comment: The js console part? well common js debugging practice… The hideDiv() bug? because it returns an error while calling it alone, so the `onclick`code doesn't go to `return false;` part

Comment: @Kaiido Why return false at the end?

Comment: Actually, the `return false` might be a problem too : In a jQuery function, it's used to prevent default behavior of the event. In Vanilla js, you should use the `event.preventDefault()` method in order to do so. check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false).
But sincerely, this hiring page is not really well written js, you should not use it to try to learn how js works.

Comment: @Kaiido When you're editing the javaScript in the inspect element editor, how do you start a new line? I looked it up and i only found shift enter for the console. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: I'm using FireBug for FF. Sorry, xan't help with Chrome's debugger. My favorite way is to override the functions, not to edit the scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `contextmenu` event for right click:

```
element.addEventListener('contextmenu', function() {
  // code here
});
```

Please don't use inline js, like `onclick` in your html. The above sample is the proper way to attach event listeners.

You should get your element reference in javascript with `var myElem = document.getElementById('the-id')` or some similar function like `document.querySelector`, etc.

Then, you can easily attach both events like this:

```
// left click
myElem.addEventListener('click', myFn);
// right click
myElem.addEventListener('contextmenu', myFn);
```

If you're adamant to do this with inline js, that would be:

```
<div onclick="myFn()" oncontextmenu="myFn()"></div>
```

Full demo of both approaches for ya:

```js
var myElem = document.getElementById('my-element');
myElem.addEventListener('click', myClickFn);
myElem.addEventListener('contextmenu', myClickFn);

function myClickFn() {
  console.log('this is myClickFn!');  
}

function someFn() {
  console.log('this is someFn!');  
}
```

```html
<div id="my-element" onclick="someFn()" oncontextmenu="someFn()">Left or Right click me!</div>
```

Also, since you're wanting to pass parameters to the function you'll be calling on click, it is good to use an intermediary function for the event, and have that function call the other function, passing the parameters, like this:

```
function myClickFn() { // this is called on click
  myOtherFunction('some', 'params');
}
```

That prevents you having to repeat the same function call, passing those same parameters in both places.

Comment: This isn't my html :) Where did you find that code? Is there not a attribute for the right click?

Comment: @committedandroider I found it in my brain :) Yes, you can add the event in the html, but it is bad practice to do so. That is the attribute `oncontextmenu`. I'm updating my answer with more detail.

Comment: For your demo, where is the console output?

Comment: @committedandroider hit f12

Comment: @committedandroider then you're probably using Safari.. google how to open the dev tools in Safari. It's silly. (google is your friend, for future reference. You don't need to ask anyone these questions).

Comment: nah chrome. I did look it up. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts. It should be F12. I don't know what's up with my computer. I am windows as well.

Comment: Ok this is weird though. A rick click or a left click causes both the things to be printed out.

Comment: @committedandroider My answer explains exactly why. If you don't want both, then change it.

Comment: But this behavior shouldn't happen though. A left click should only trigger the 'click' callback or a the call to myClickFn which prints out "this is my myClickFn!"

Comment: @committedandroider please, read the code. It has both. If you only want one, then remove the other.

Comment: do you know how to save changes as you go along? http://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/ says to do a control s but when I did a control s, I was meet with a  dialog asking me if I wanted to save the whole html file in my documents...... I want to save JavaScript code changes.

Comment: @committedandroider I wouldn't be doing anything like that in my console. Not sure. I believe that only works for local files, not files being hosted online.

Comment: Sorry should have clarified. I meant the debugger, not the console, so i can make changes to the code and see what the difference is in the printing. Not the console.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to close your `onclick` string at the end with a **"**:

```
onclick="jvAddAttachment2('jvcoverletter', 'qLY9Vfwx')"
```

And left click instead of right clicking.

Comment: Yeah I got it show up with a left click. that isn't my onclick method. It still works without the ". Do you know why it doesn't show up with a right click? A right click still is a click

Comment: You would have to use `oncontextmenu="jvAddAttachment2('jvcoverletter', 'qLY9Vfwx')"` instead.  Yes it is a click, just a different type of click called a `contextmenu`.

Comment: Is there also a special JavaScript name for the left click as well? Or is that just a click?

Comment: do you use chrome for inspecting?

Comment: Yes.  Firefox also has an inspector too.

Answer (score 0):

```
 onclick="jvAddAttachment2('jvcoverletter', 'qLY9Vfwx')"
```

I think that double quotation was absent.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jakiir/mp44yyg0/2/)

Comment: The problem wasn't with that function.

Comment: When you inspect element, you do you use the Chrome Inspect element tool?

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.